# Edit modal and update the values in jQuery datatable using Jquery-Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, sharepoint, datatables

Data fetched from SharePoint list displayed as a jQuery datatable which possess edit button for every items in a table. After clicking edit button, it displays a bootstrap modal from where we can edit and update details and saved back to the jQuery datatable.

My issue here is when I have edited and saved an item. It saved as a new item in an jQuery datatable, it is not editing the item which i have selected.

Data need to get updated and saved after editing each row

Comment: can you share the code you have now

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can follow the guidelines in [mre]. You can also take the [tour] and read [ask] for more background and guidance.